# jQuery click on images and "copy/paste" append img element value into input of type text

Tags: jquery, html

It is about chat script in which users can click on images of emoji so that value can be inserted into input of type text. I have it working good but problem is when I click on different img emoji I want that img element value.

jquery

```
$(document).on('click', '.copy', function(){
        $('.paste').val(function(index, val){
            return val + $('.copy').attr('value');
        });

});
```

html

```
<form id="frmsend" method="post" action="process.php">
<div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control paste" type="text" name="text" id="text" placeholder="type your text here" autofocus />
    <div class="input-group-append">
           <input class="form-control" type="submit" name="send" value="Send" id="send" />
    </div>
</div>
</form>
<img class="copy" src="openmoji/1F642.svg" height="40" width="40" value=":)"></img>
<img class="copy" src="openmoji/1F609.svg" height="40" width="40" value=";)"></img>
<img class="copy" src="openmoji/1F600.svg" height="40" width="40" value=":D"></img>
<img class="copy" src="openmoji/1F618.svg" height="40" width="40" value=":*"></img>
<img class="copy" src="openmoji/1F606.svg" height="40" width="40" value="xD"></img>
<img class="copy" src="openmoji/1F61C.svg" height="40" width="40" value=";P"></img>
<img class="copy" src="openmoji/1F61B.svg" height="40" width="40" value=":P"></img>
<img class="copy" src="openmoji/1F61D.svg" height="40" width="40" value="xP"></img>
```

actual demo of problem

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to take the value of the clicked emoji using `this` so the function will turn like this.
With your function it takes the first element.

```
$(document).on('click', '.copy', function(){
        const emoji = $(this).attr('value');
        $('.paste').val(function(index, val){
            return val + emoji;
        });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use this little code to do the function. - Using jQuery

```
$('.copy').click(function(){
    var image = $(this).attr('value');
    $('#text').val($('#text').val() + image);
});
```

If you wanted to to have the input value just one image value you can replace the code with - just replace `$('#text').val($('#text').val() + image);` with `$('#text').val(image);`, which will look:

```
$('.copy').click(function(){
    var image = $(this).attr('value');
    $('#text').val(image);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '.copy', function(e){
let v = $(".paste").val();
       $(".paste").val(
       v + e.target.getAttribute("value")
       )
});
```

I hope this will help you Good luck 
 - Adel Chemache